# Yii2: AssetManager.php deleted automatic in Yii2 Advanced

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, cloud-hosting

I used web cloud hosting and my project in Yii2 advanced framework, when I uploaded it, in `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php` in deleted automatic.
When I asked from hosting they says your file has symlink!

How can fix it?

Comment: You should run a composer update command in your project in order to restore any lost vendor files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that you have "asset" in your .gitignore or .gitexclude. The deployment will then not include any ignored files like app/assets but also not AssetManager.php

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-publishing, maybe you have set your asset publishing using symbolic link.

You can set the configuration in `config/main.php`

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'linkAssets' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```